# Error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntVar' and 'int'

Tags: tkinter

So, this is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()

var = IntVar()

def mais():
    global var
    var = var + 1

l = Label(app, textvariable = var)
l.pack()
b = Button(app, textvariable = var, command = mais)
b.pack()
```

I want when I press the button, the label update the variable and show it, but when I press the button, this error apppears:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntVar' and 'int'
```

Comment: have you read the documentation on `IntVar` to learn how to get the value out of the variable?

Answer (score 3):

IntVar gives you an object, not int.
Try

```
from tkinter import IntVar
X=IntVar()
X.set( X.get() + 1 )
```

instead.

Comment: your code won't run. It's `X.set` not `X.Set`. Also, it's not `IntVar.get()` but `X.get()`

Comment: Sorry.  Typing in a hurry is not a good thing. You are right for sure.